# Date Time from Django views to be used in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, datetime

I have this view in views.py:

```
def endtime(request, *args, **kwargs):
    end_time = datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=10) 
    return HttpResponse(end_time)
```

The value returned by this view is **2016-01-31 16:25:09.622489**

I have a Javascript function that sends an Ajax request to above view and the returned value is recieved by **data** parameter,

```
function myfun(){
  $.get('/endtime/',function(data){
        var date = new Date(); 
        var diff = data - date; //not working
  });
}
```

The value of **data** is **2016-01-31 16:25:09.622489** and **date** is **Sun Jan 31 2016 06:38:47 GMT+0530 (IST)**

How can I convert either **data** into **date** format or **vice-versa** so that I can take the difference between them.

Comment: You could try convert `data` from string to a js Date object. Try `data = new Date(data)`

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got data as a string, and convert it to Date object first.
by function  Date.parse(dateString) or new Date(dateString)